# Metacity, put "roll up" back in context menu?

Tags: context-menu, title-bar, metacity

In Metacity, for a while, if you right-clicked a titlebar (or pressed alt-space), "Roll up" was one of the menuitems.

These days, it's gone, which is disappointing since it was the only thing in that menu I have ever selected.

Is there a way to bring it back, or is that menu hardcoded in C?

Comment: Alternative: Point at the titlebar and use the scroll wheel. (IIRC.) If the menu is useless, just don't use it.

Comment: grawity: I have no scroll wheel here (they hurt my hand).  If I'm using my mouse, I can double-click, but the big advantage of having it in the menu is that I could "alt-space u" to roll up without having to reach for my mouse at all.